# How do I formally write down a Euclidean space with symbols?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, notation, euclidean-geometry

A space is an ordered tuple, where the first element is a set and the following elements are describing the added structure, e.g. $(X, m)$ for a metric space, $(X, \tau)$ for a topological space. What are the following elements for a Euclidean space?

As far as I understand we need

- $X=\mathbb R^n$ is the set of all n-tuples of real numbers (with $n\in\mathbb N$)
- we need the elements of $X$ to be vectors - so linearly combine-able with the scalar multiplication $\times$, the field $F$ and addition $+$.
- a dot product $\cdot$ between the elements of $X$.
- a norm for the elements of $X$. Is this inherently included in the dot product or do I need to state it explicitly to be precise? Don't I need an additional "$-$"? http://faculty.cord.edu/ahendric/2008Fall210/subsub.pdf suggests that this is also included in the "$+$".
- completeness of $X$ (is this inherently included in the fact that $X=\mathbb R^n$?)
- a metric (I think this is also inherently included in the norm and the fact that the elements of $X$ are vectors, right?)

From that I infer, that a Euclidean space is $(\mathbb R^n, \cdot, +, F, \times)$. Possibly I also need a "$-$".

So: How do I formally write down a Euclidean space with symbols?

Comment: Simply $\mathbb R^n$ may suffice, because the addition, product, norm, etc. are standard

Comment: I am not sure what your $F$ is supposed to be. As the other comment says, the operations on $\Bbb{R}^n$ are standard but if you want to list a primitive set of operation, then: (1) you do need the ring (or field) operations on $\Bbb{R}$, but from your metric space example, it looks like you are taking those as given and (2) there is no canonical choice e.g., a norm (satisfying an appropriate axiom) and a dot product are interdefinable. Negation can be axiomatised using addition. Alternatively addition can be defined using subtraction and negation.

Comment: @RobArthan: The $F$ is the field (see the second bullet point).

Comment: I missed that, possibly because your first bullet implied the field was $\Bbb{R}$. Thanks.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: I want to build a new space $(X, \Xi, ...)$ where $\Xi$ is a special finite set of disjoint subsets of $X$ (not a topology or anything like that).

Comment: @RobArthan: I was not aware that my first bullet point implied anything like that - I certainly did not intend to imply this :-). What else do I need? Do I need the minus? Am I right to leave out norm, completeness, metric, and other stuff like a topology?  Is there a way to summarize some of the symbols I used so far by necessary implication (as I did with norm, metric, ...)?

Comment: Well there are lots of vector spaces whose universe is not $\Bbb{R}^n$. As I said there is no canonical choice for the signature, e.g., any one of a norm a metric or an inner product will do. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)#Many-sorted_structures

Comment: @RobArthan: Sure, there are lots of other vector spaces - and I am interested in the one which underlying set is $\mathbb R^n$. I want to know what the signature specifically for the Euclidean space is - not for any space. I am probably missing what you point is, since I am a novice in these topics - sorry.

Comment: Why use any more symbols than $\mathbb{R}^n$? This symbol should stand for the product vector space $\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{R}$ of a finite number of copies of $\mathbb{R}$, which is to be considered as a 1-dimensional vector space over itself. This gives $\mathbb{R}^n$ the product vector space structure and the product norm, thus endowing it with the correct topology. Thus it includes all the information you need provided you have made the correct definitions on $\mathbb{R}$ in the first place.

Comment: @Tyrone: As far as I understand $\mathbb R^n$ stands for the Cartesian product of reals. I looked up product space and it seems that $\Pi$ is for the Cartesian product? I only knew it from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Capital_pi_notation. I don't understand "which is to be considered as a 1-dimensional vector space over itself". I also don't have the background knowledge to understand why this would give the "product vector space structure and the product norm" and what the "correct definitions" are. Can you write this in an answer or point me to simple introductory material?

Comment: Vector spaces are the domain of [linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra). The point is that the vector addition, scalar multiplication, and norm become encoded in the definition of the product (which is basic). The product norm induces a complete metric (this is a theorem). The idea is to avoid horrible notation and encode it instead in the mathematics.

Comment: @Tyrone: I guess that when you write "the product (which is basic)" you mean the Cartesian product? So, where does the dot product between two Euclidean vectors come from? I see that a real number can be multiplied with another real number, but I do not see how the standard dot product would directly follow from this.

Comment: I mean the product of vector spaces. Follow the link. If $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then their dot product is $x\cdot y=\frac{1}{2}(\|x+y\|^2-\|x\|^2-\|y\|^2)$, where $\|-\|$ is the norm I have defined by the product. (the defininion *gives* $\|x\|=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}$)

Comment: @Tyrone: I had followed the link, and I am - more or less - aware of what a vector space is. My understanding was the that the norm was induced by the dot product $\|x\| = \sqrt{x \cdot x}$, where $x \cdot y = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i \cdot y_i)$. I think you are describing this, but slightly differently? I am not sure. What I am not seeing is $x \cdot y = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i \cdot y_i)$ would be "obvious".

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}(\|x+y\|^2-\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)=\frac{1}{2}(\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i+y_i)^2-x_i^2-y_i^2)=\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{i=1}^n2x_iy_i)=\sum^n_{i=1}x_iy_i$. This is literally the equation I just wrote for you. When working over the reals in finite-dimensions it is equivalent to give the norm or the dot product.

Comment: @Tyrone: Ok, but then the question is just moving to the norm: What definition gives the multivariate norm? I don't see it mentioned for the real number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Definition) and even if I saw it, it would not be obvious that the product space over the real number would need to be definited the way we did.

Comment: If $(U,\|-\|_U),(V,\|-\|_V)$ are normed vector spaces over the reals define their product to be the vector space $U\times V$ with its product structure given the norm $\|(u,v)\|_{U\times V}=\sqrt{\|u\|_U^2+\|v\|_V^2}$

Comment: @Tyrone: Where do you get this from? The [Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm) seem to be just one possible norm over the real numbers, so it does not seem to me that we can omit this while defining the Euclidean space. 1) I did not find anywhere that real numbers are normed *by definition*.  2) You define the norm, but I don't see that this definition *must* be the case. And if you define it, shouldn't this particular dot product (other dot products are thinkable) be part of the def. of the Euclidean space (not just implied)? What am I missing?

Comment: I wrote it down. It wasn't difficult and it correctly returns the euclidean norm when the norm on $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^1$ is provided. Remember that this was my suggestion from the get-go. $1)$ the real numbers are not normed by definition. You still have to define this. Again I said this above. $2)$ I am not suggesting it *must* be the case. My suggestion is to *define* this case. It seems sensible since it returns the euclidean norm. I don't see why I need to include the dot product in the definition, as I showed above that it is just the dot product associated with the (product) norm.

Comment: @Tyrone: Maybe we misunderstand each other. I understand that you define everything correctly here. My point is not that your definitions are lacking. My point is that you define it here, but that when I see the symbol $\mathbb R^n$ for the product space of the real numbers, that *alone* does not seem to imply to me that *your definition from here* is used. Thus, if I want to state that I am using the Euclidean space with the Euclidean norm etc., than I need to say that, and it is not enough to just mention the symbol $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Of course, convention might imply that I am *mean* the Euclidean space when I write "$\mathbb R^n$", but this is just because of convention - thus abuse of notation - not because the Euclidean norm *must* follow from the product space over the real numbers. That is how I understood all of this. Now, first I got the impression that you meant that the Euclidean norm (as you defined it) *must* follow from a product space over the real numbers, but maybe that was a misunderstanding.

Comment: No. That wasn't my implication. On $\mathbb{R}$ the Euclidean norm is *defined* by $\|x\|=|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$. This either gives you the dot product, or comes from the dot product $x\cdot y=xy$ as I outlined above. The euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is then just that defined by taking (finite) products of $\mathbb{R}$. Using these definitions you get the standard norm, dot product and metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and (you can show that) the metric is complete as a consequence of the fact that the metric on $\mathbb{R}$ which is induced by the norm you defined is complete (which you show).

Comment: Maybe I thought you were asking for a *definition* of what euclidean space should be.

Comment: @Tyrone: Possible, yeah, but I was not asking for the definition. Glad, we got that out of the way. I tried to rephrase my (new) problem in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3925343/are-all-product-topologies-spaces-over-real-numbers-euclidean-spaces?noredirect=1#3925363

Answer (score 1):

You already wrote down a Euclidean space in your question: $\mathbb{R}$.

The only other thing I can think of that you might want to include is your metric. Say $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is a metric space and define d, which is the distance of any two points.

There are some axioms to remember for metrics:

1. $d(x,x)=0$
2. $d(x,y)>0$
3. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
4. $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ (called the triangle inequality; think of a right triangle, and you walk in a diagonal line to get where you need to go)

There are many metrics we could define for a space like $\mathbb{R^2}$, the real plane; the most common being $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$

---

**EDIT:**

You would need to learn some topology I suppose. The Cartesian product is just one example of a more general concept which is product spaces. In topology we discuss continuity and open sets (they are not all defined the same). Say $X,Y$ are topological spaces, and the set, $U_{X_i}$ and $V_{Y_i}$ are open in their respective topologies.

We define the topology on the **product space** $X\,\,x\,\, V$ by just saying it "inherits" the topology of the other two spaces. A subset of $X\,\,x\,\, V$ is open if an only if $U\subset X$ and $V\subset Y$ are both open. This applies exactly the same way to our standard metric spaces, but instead the product space will inherit the metric, which can be thought of as giving us an idea of what "open" is as well!

Comment: From my understanding, saying the $\mathbb R^n$ is the Euclidean space is an [abuse of notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation), but since I want to build a new space https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3925036/how-do-i-formally-write-down-a-euclidean-space-with-symbols?noredirect=1#comment8094639_3925036, I need the explicit symbols. Without the abuse of notation I understand that $\mathbb R^n = \mathbb R \times ...  \times \mathbb R$ is just the set of n-tuples of real numbers (or the respective Cartesian product $\times$ of reals). Also, did you omit ${}^n$ on purpose?

Comment: @Make42, alright, then you would need to learn a little topology to do product spaces, but it's very easy.

Comment: I guess you would need to point me to some specific text in order to get me going. Otherwise I am not sure I understand what you are referring to. (Disclaimer: I am not a pure mathematician, I am "just" an engineer doing applied math in daily life.)

Comment: @Make42 Check my edit.

Comment: That was helpful - I understand that part of a product space is that they inherit the topology of the other two spaces. Also - which I was not aware of - it seems (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Definition) that the reals are not just the set of numbers itself (what I thought), but also the "stuff that you can do with them", namely $+,\cdot,<$. But I do not yet see how this directly leads to $\cdot,+,F,\times$ for the elements of the product space. E.g. I use a totally different dot product (which is done with the [kernel trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method)).

Comment: I see... it seems I thought the real numbers are the same as the "reals" in set theory, but they are called [Baire space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_(set_theory)). (The question of how this directly leads to ... is still not clear though.)

Comment: @Make42 hmm... I think I see your problem maybe. There are many different ways to define addition, subtraction, multiplication... I know a lot more about vector spaces than I do about rings, but we don't have to define multiplication in the way we do. The only rings I've studied are the kind that multiplication maps RxR -> R, i.e. natural multiplication. Check out this pdf that has the axioms that define a ring.

http://www.maths.nuigalway.ie/MA416/section1-2.pdf

Comment: @Make42 on the axioms that define ordering: https://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/real-analysis/order-axioms-for-real-numbers.html#:~:text=The%20axioms%20of%20order%20in,then%20ac%3Ebc.

Comment: @Make42 One last thing. Unless you are inventing a number system (invent really is the right word) or considering an exotic example - you don't need to state axioms constantly. Natural arithmetic and geometry simply makes sense. While these things might not necessarily be defined this way for every system, we don't really need to say anything more than we are working with a n-dimensional Euclidean vector space. We don't even need to state what the norm is, unless we are going to actually use it... in other words R^n is in no way an abuse of notation, it is a very useful, unambiguous one.

Comment: Please note that an "abuse of notation" is nothing bad. It is in fact it is pretty standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation

Comment: I formulated the questions that arose for me in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3925343/are-all-product-spaces-over-real-numbers-euclidean-spaces